# Rust: E0562 when implementing generic trait

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I am trying out Rust and ❤️ it so far.

But currently I am stuck with generic traits :)

**Status Quo:**

There is this trait I want to implement, which I cannot modify:

```rust
pub trait Handler<R, B, E> {
    fn run(&mut self, event: http::Request<B>) -> Result<R, E>;
}
```

One implementation of that trait in the same library is:

```rust
impl<Function, R, B, E> Handler<R, B, E> for Function
where
    Function: FnMut(http::Request<B>) -> Result<R, E>,
{
    fn run(&mut self, event: http::Request<B>) -> Result<R, E> {
        (*self)(event)
    }
}
```

And this implementation can be used as follows:

```rust
fn handler(req: http::Request<Body>) -> Result<impl IntoResponse, MyError> {
    ...
}
```

With the `IntoReponse` trait:

```rust
pub trait IntoResponse {
    fn into_response(self) -> Response<Body>;
}
```

**What I want to do:**

I want to implement that trait for a struct to be able to be used with the types mentioned above.

I tried:

```rust
impl Handler<impl IntoResponse, Body, MyError> for GQLHandler {
    fn run(&mut self, req: http::Request<Body>) -> Result<impl IntoResponse, MyError> {
        ...
    }
}
```

But that results in the errors:

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
  --> handlers/gql.rs:18:14
   |
18 | impl Handler<impl IntoResponse, Body, NowError> for GQLHandler {
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
  --> handlers/gql.rs:19:59
   |
19 |     fn run(&mut self, req: http::Request<Body>) -> Result<impl IntoResponse, NowError> {
   |                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It works of cause if I implement it for a specific type, e.g.

```rust
impl Handler<http::Response<Body>, Body, NowError> for GQLHandler {
    fn run(&mut self, req: http::Request<Body>) -> Result<http::Response<Body>, NowError> {
```

but I would like to keep the `impl Trait` somehow.

*Looking forward to any suggestions.*

Thanks & Cheers
Thomas

***EDIT:***

Following up on @MaxV's answer (Thanks!), sadly that did not work for me (which is why I did not accept this answer yet).

[See this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1e4e37c8f6faf1abe3ef01622bcd66db)

When trying to return `Ok(...)` with a type implementing `IntoResponse`, I get the following error:

```
  |
3 | impl<T: IntoResponse> Handler<T, Body, MyError> for GQLHandler {
  |      - this type parameter
4 |     fn run(&mut self, req: Request<Body>) -> Result<T, MyError> {
5 |         Ok(Response::<()>::new(()))
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found struct `http::Response`
  |
  = note: expected type parameter `T`
                     found struct `http::Response<()>`
```

even though I implemented `IntoResponse` for `Response`:

```rust
trait IntoResponse{
    fn foo(&self);
}

impl IntoResponse for Response<()>
{
    fn foo(&self) {}
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**New answer**

It feels like you're looking for [Existential types](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2071-impl-trait-existential-types.html):

> Right now, it isn't possible to return an `impl Trait` type from a trait implementation. This is a huge restriction which this RFC fixes <...>

[Existential types RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2071) was merged but the implementation doesn't stabilized. You can track the progress [there](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063).

**Original answer**

You can't use `impl` there but you can solve it this way:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ee855c06031a5d87b09eb8702bf82b83)

```
impl<T: IntoResponse> Handler<T, Body, MyError> for GQLHandler {
    fn run(&mut self, req: http::Request<Body>) -> Result<T, MyError> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Removed my previous comment because I updated the original question accordingly.

Comment: Hey @thlcodes, could you please explain why you're trying to avoid `Result<http::Response<Body>, NowError>` approach? The explanation should help me to peak the best answer for you.

Comment: Of cause. `IntoResponse` is also implemented for `Into<Body>` and even `serde_json::Value` and I would like to use those for cleaner code as well. But mainly I want to understand why this does not work und learn :)

Comment: @thlcodes, I've updated the answer. Please take a look.

Comment: I am not able to return an object that implements `IntoResponse` in your example. Here's [my attempt](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=29c1872d398fd2d5830bfe626b802b99). I get "expected type parameter `T`, found struct `Return`" even though I think `Return` is a `T`. What am I getting wrong?